# How to rename a google spreadsheet via Google Drive API in python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, gspread

I'm using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) in Python to make archiving of my files.
However i am having an issue renaming the copy of my original file.

The title of my new file defaults to

> 'Copy of + original filename'

However I want my new file's name is

> 'original filename + current date'

I can't find how to change the title configure in the copied code or rename the new file I have copied.

The copy code I used is:

```
service.files().copy(fileId=original_file_id).execute()
```

Does anyone know how to rename a file title in Python? Or any alternate method will also be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure how exactly you want the date and the copied file name to be formatted, but you can do the following:

- Retrieve the name of the original file via [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).
- Copy the file via [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy), and retrieve the copied file ID.
- Build the desired name, using the name of the original file and whatever date you have.
- Update the copy with the new name, via [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update).

#### Code snippet:

```
from datetime import date

def copyFile(service, fileId):
    fileName = service.files().get(fileId=fileId).execute()["name"]
    copyId = service.files().copy(fileId=fileId).execute()["id"]
    currentDate = date.today()
    copyName = "{} | {}".format(fileName, currentDate)
    body = { "name": copyName }
    service.files().update(fileId=copyId, body=body).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note i am not a python developer this code is a wild guess on my part you will need to fix it.

The [Files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) has a parameter called name which you can send with the request. I am not sure how the optional parameters are sent with the python libray.   The only issue i see with this is that you will need to do a file.get first so that you have the current name of the file that you can use to pass to this method.

```
request = service.files().copy(fileId=original_file_id);
request.Name =  'original file name + current date';
response = request.execute();
```